# Requirements for running a JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

Which requirements does a system have to meet to run a JavaFX application?
Is it enough to have a JRE installed?

Comment: Define system. For different sysems the answer may be different.

Comment: See [Oracle JDK and JRE 8 Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JavaFX Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#5):

> **5. Is JavaFX included in Java SE?**
>
> As of JavaFX 2.2 and Java SE 7 update 6, the JavaFX libraries are installed as part of Java SE; a standalone version of JavaFX 2.2 will remain available for Java SE 6 users (Windows only) until Java SE 6 reaches End-of-Life in February 2013.

Or [JavaFX Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#A1095238) (Java SE 8)

> **Availability**
>
> The JavaFX APIs are available as a fully integrated feature of the Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) and the Java Development Kit (JDK ). Because the JDK is available for all major desktop platforms (Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux), JavaFX applications compiled to JDK 7 and later also run on all the major desktop platforms. Support for ARM platforms has also been made available with JavaFX 8. JDK for ARM includes the base, graphics and controls components of JavaFX.
>
> The cross-platform compatibility enables a consistent runtime experience for JavaFX applications developers and users. Oracle ensures synchronized releases and updates on all platforms and offers an extensive support program for companies that run mission-critical applications.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2.htm documentation gives detail information for requirements.